# What are you doing/going-to-do this evening?

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference

In *Grammar and Vocabulary for First Certificate* (Prodromou, 2005), Chapter 2 covers "the future", "be going to", "present continuous", and "present simple". I put three of the End-Of-Chapter questions below with the corresponding back-of-the-book answers.  **My concern is with Question #1 only.** (I wrote #2 and #3 for context.)

> **Put the verb in brackets into the most suitable form of the future.**
>
> 1. "What **________** you **__________** this evening?" (**do**) 'Nothing.' **`[Answer: are ... doing]`**
> 2. "Well, **_______** we **___________** to that new pizzeria?" (**go**) **`[Answer: shall ... go]`**
> 3. In 2004 the Olympic Games **_________** in Athens. (**take place**) **`[Answer: will take place]`**

For Question #1, the only answer in the back-of-the-book answer is the present continuous: "What **are** you **doing** this evening?"  This has effectively ruled-out the possibility of using 'be going to' to complete the sentence. In other words, I think what he is saying is that "What **are** you **going to do** this evening?" is incorrect.

Do you think he is right?

Comment: Could you share an example of what you think might be correct? Something like "I will *be going* to the store later."?

Comment: Here is an example: A. What are you going to do tonight? B. I'm going to see a film.

Comment: Your example **doesn't** use 'be going to'.  Can you show the sentence that you think is correct, with those words?

Comment: It IS using "be going to". Note the difference: What are you doing tonight? ( present continuous used for fixed arrangemets) Vs. What are you going to do tonight? (be going to used for plans)

Comment: I can't really endorse [*"What will you be going to do?"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22what+will+you+be+going+to+do%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but it's hard to argue that such a form is somehow "ungrammatical". It just doesn't make sense. Probably because *will be"* and *"going to"* both indicate "future tense", and we don't know how to conceptualise "future future".

Comment: I would pay no attention to [Luck Prodromou](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Luck+Prodromou&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=Luck+Prodromou&aqs=chrome..69i57.58342295j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). There are no "insights" to be gained by considering this aspect of English grammar in terms of particular words that may appear before or after "you" in the example context.

Comment: But my question has nothing to do with "what will you be going to do?", FumbleFinger. My question is whether the following sentences are both proper English or not? 1. What are you doing tonight? 2. What are you going to do tonight?

Comment: @Mohammad: The form *"What are you doing?"* implies "present tense". English doesn't actually have a "future tense". If you append *"tonight"* as in your example, you contextually force a "future" interpretation which wouldn't otherwise be available. You can also ask *"What **will you be doing** tonight?"*, in which case the *grammar* (of the auxiliary "will") forces "future". All I'm saying is that Prodromou's presentation may not be all that helpful at your level - it's *linguistics*, not *grammar*.

Comment: But we can use present continuous with a future meaning to talk about arrangements we have made for the future, usually with people. For example, I can't go out tomorrow night. I'm having dinner with my mrandparents.

Comment: I think your question could be improved/edited to include some info you gave in these comments. I'm having a bit of trouble "digging into" your intended meaning / issue. Literally, it seems you're asking "What are you **be going to** this evening?" is correct.  I'm sure you're not asking that, but then should I (as reader) need to decide which conjugation you intend, and could that be part of the issue you are running into?  Too many variables and too much work on the reader to decipher, IMO.

Comment: @Mohammad: I'm just commenting, not *answering*. But note that there's nothing unusual about ["what do you do next"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22what+do+you+do+next%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and it can be semantically *identical* to ["what **will** you do next"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22what+will+you+do+next%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). There is some "sense" to how English handles the future without using future tense "verb inflexions", but I don't think your example context would usually be useful in terms of showing how it works syntactically.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: "What are you be going to this evening?" is not what I mean. By "be going to" I mean "am/is/are going to" depending on the subject. So the question should be: " What ARE you GOING TO do?"

Comment: @MohammadNazar Please _edit_ your _question_ to include your proposed alternative sentence. You have mentioned it in your comments, but it should be clear by now that a lot of people are still puzzled.

Comment: @ oerkelens: All I need to know is whether the following sentences are proper English or not: What are you doing tonight?/// What are you going to do tonight?

Comment: We ask you to edit your proposed alternative sentence into your question so it the question will be understood by answerers without struggling through this long chain of comments, and so the question will still be of value to future readers if the comments are deleted.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Very nice revision CHL. That's MUCH clearer.

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Much better than the original one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you: *What are you going to do this evening?* is just as acceptable and ordinary way of asking this question as *What are you doing this evening?*

Within the given parameters, so are:

> What will you be doing this evening?
>   What are you going to be doing this evening?

Even this, which is ordinarily a very stilted way of expressing it, may be appropriate and natural in some circumstances:

> What will you do this evening?

But this doesn’t necessarily mean that the book is wrong; it may be that something in the instructions excludes constructions with *BE going to* from consideration in this particular question.

Comment: @Stonry B: Thanks for providing me with more sentences. I do agree with you. The book is quite useful.